# StoryBoardを使わないtabBarControllerの扱い方について

Tags: ios, objective-c

StoryBoardを使わずにtabBarAppを作っています。AppDelegate.mに以下のようなコードを書いています。

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    //tabBarの生成
    [self initTabBar];

    if([self isFirstRun]){
        //初回起動の場合、別のviewControllerに遷移
    }

    return YES;
}
```

初回起動時に表示されるviewControllerはtabBarもnavigationBarも使っていません。初回設定が終わった後に通常時はじめに表示されるviewControllerに遷移すると、tabBarが生成されません。初回設定のviewControllerをすべて破棄してはじめの画面に遷移したいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか。

---追記---
ご指摘ありがとうございます。以下がinitTabBarのコードです。

```
-(void)initTabBar{
    FirstTabViewController *firstTabViewController = [[FirstTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    SecondTabViewController *secondTabViewController = [[SecondTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    ThirdTabViewController *thirdTabViewController = [[ThirdTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstTabViewController, secondTabViewController, thirdTabViewController, nil];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

    firstTabViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"first" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
    secondTabViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"second" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
    thirdTabViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"third" image:nil selectedImage:nil];

    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

---さらに追記---
ご指摘ありがとうございます。以下がisFirstRunのコードです。

```
-(BOOL)isFirstRun{
 NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 if([ud objectForKey:@"firstRunDate"]){
     return NO;
 }
 return YES;
}
```

初回起動の場合の処理については以下のように行っています。

```
SetupViewController *setupVC = [[SetupViewController alloc] init];
[self.window setRootViewController:setupVC];
```

また、SetupViewControllerでの設定が終了したあとは以下のようなコードで遷移させています。

```
FirstTabViewController *firstTabVC = [[FirstTabViewController alloc] init];
firstTabVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:firstTabVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

すると、遷移後にTabBarが表示されないという問題が生じます。

Comment: tabBarAppというのは、`UITabBarController`を使ったアプリケーションという意味でしょうか。`initTabBar`で行われている処理の妥当性、初回起動時の画面遷移の方法が分からないので回答が難しいと思います。（可能な範囲で実装を公開すると良いと思います）

Comment: `initTabBar`の実装よりも、むしろ「//初回起動の場合、別のviewControllerに遷移」の実装のほうに、問題箇所があるように見受けられます。それと、`isFirstRun`の実装も開示してもらうと、より問題点のありかが明確になるだろうと推測されます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetupViewController`を`rootViewController`に指定した時点で、`UITabbarController`以下のビューコントローラを破棄してしまっているためです。再生成しているのは`FirstTabViewController`なのでタブが表示されなくなります。

実装の方針はいくつかありますが、UITabbarControllerを一度だけ生成するのが良いと思います。

```
SetupViewController *setupVC = [[SetupViewController alloc] init];
[self.window setRootViewController:setupVC];
```

この処理を、

```
SetupViewController *setupVC = [[SetupViewController alloc] init];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:setupVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

に変えます。そして、`setupVC`でやりたい処理が終わったら、

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

を実行すれば、`UITabbarController`が表示されると思います。

もし`setupVC`から他の`ViewController`を`presentViewController:animated:completion:`で呼び出している場合は、`setupVC`に対して`dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`を実行すれば、途中の`ViewController`は全て破棄されます。